# Pairwise Maximum Metric

Tags: combinatorics, vector-spaces, metric-spaces

Well , I had question on vector spaces and maximum metric . Lets us assume a set of vectors of $N$ dimension containing only **integers** , and let us make a set of vectors then we will calculate the maximum of the pairwise distance of vectors from the set where distance between two vectors is given by maximum metric and let us call this the $X$ .

Now , I thought how many sets I can make with a fixed value of X .
Then I found out that there can be infinite such sets.

So to limit them I have considered two sets to be similar if there is a vector $C$ such that if added to the vectors of set $A$ we can obtain the set $B$.

**For Eg :-**
Here $A$ and $B$ are sets of $2D$ vectors

$A = [(4,4) (1,2)]$

$B = [(2,3) (5,5)]$

Here $C$ will be $(1,1)$ as we can see by adding $C$ to $A$ we get $[(5,5) (2,3)]$ which is equivalent to $B$.

Now , we again count the number of different sets of N dimension vectors with a fixed value of X.

I have solved for $1D$ vectors and it comes out to be $2^{X-1}$.
But I cannot further solve it for higher dimensions .

Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Are the entries in your vectors real?  integers?  How many vectors in a set?  It appears you are thinking about the sets being ordered, so it makes sense to talk of the first element of A-usually they are not.  When you subtracted the vectors in A and B you were careful to maintain the order.  Your similarity relation is not transitive (consider $C=[(3,4)(6,6)]$- we have $A \sim B, B \sim C, A \not \sim C$  I think your question needs some work.

Comment: Yes , you are right I missed some details let me reframe it .

Comment: I think now it should be transitive as I have removed the order contraint .

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to compute.  Maybe if you show how you got $2^{X-1}$ for 1D vectors it will be clear.  My C was another set of vectors to be compared with A and B.  I found it was equivalent to B but not A.  When you don't have a transitive relation, you don't have equivalence classes and you can't count things up to equivalence.

Comment: Why won't $[(n,2n)(n,3n)]$ be an infinite set of inequivalent sets of vectors?

Comment: but wont this type of sets have different value of X ?

Comment: And in case of 1D vectors , I have counted them like this , 
that they will be points on a line , and if X is the fixed value then any set must contain 2 points at distance of X , between those two point there are X - 1 points which can be added in to the set or not , that is why the count I got was $2^{X-1}$

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12375/discussion-between-ross-millikan-and-mod)

Comment: I put my conclusion below.  I found an error in our chat session for the one corner case and fixed it.

Comment: Now there is a final answer, removing the overcount.

Answer (score 1):

After chat with OP I believe I have a better problem statement and a partial solution.

Consider an $(X+1) \times (X+1)$ array of lattice points.  How many subsets of the set of points are there that include a pair of points on opposite sides (so the subset will not fit into a smaller square) and subsets that differ by a translation are considered the same?  First we consider subsets that differ by translation different-we will subtract the overcount later.  Let $f(X)$ be the number of subsets that touch two opposite sides.  Let $h(X)$ be the number we want, the number of subsets with translations considered the same.

If we have at least two of the corner points, which we can choose in $11$ ways, we can have any subset of the remaining points.  This gives $11\cdot 2^{(X+1)^2-4}$

If we have just one corner point ($4$ choices), we need at least one point on one of the other two sides and any of the other points.  The corners are not allowed.  This gives $4 \cdot (2^{2X-2}-1)2^{X^2-1}$

If we have no corner points, we need two on opposite sides.  If we insist on left and right, there are $2^{X-1}-1$ subsets of the left side with no corners, the same for the right side, $2^{X-1}$ for each of the top and bottom, giving $(2^{X-1}-1)^22^{2X-2}$ borders with right and left sides.  We have a similar count for borders with top and bottom, but have double counted the number with all four sides, so we get a total of $2(2^{X-1}-1)^22^{2X-2}-(2^{X-1}-1)^4$ borders.  For each of them we can have any combination of interior points.  This gives a factor $2^{(X-1)^2}$ for a total of $(2(2^{X-1}-1)^22^{2X-2}-(2^{X-1}-1)^4)2^{(X-1)^2}$

The grand total is the sum of these, $f(X)=11\cdot 2^{(X+1)^2-4}+4 \cdot (2^{2X-2}-1)2^{X^2-1}+(2(2^{X-1}-1)^22^{2X-2}-(2^{X-1}-1)^4)2^{(X-1)^2}$

As I said, this is an overcount because subsets that differ by a translation are counted separately.  I believe that to handle that we will have to assess rectangular regions as well as squares and use inclusion/exclusion.  For $X=1$ the count should be $9$, not $11$, because $\{(0,0),(0,1)\}$ and $\{(1,0),(1,1)\}$ are considered the same, as are $\{(0,0),(1,0)\}$ and $\{(0,1),(1,1)\}$

We now find the overcount for translation.  Define $g(X,Y)$ as the number of subsets of an $(X+1) \times (Y+1)$ lattice that include a point on each of the four sides.  A corner point is counted on both sides.  The idea is that these subsets with $X \gt Y$ can be translated in $X-Y$ ways and are not double counted because we require all four sides.  We follow a similar approach to the above, changed because we need all four sides.

We can have enough corner points to satisfy all four sides in $7$ ways-all four, any three, or two diagonal.  The rest of the points are optional.  That gives $7\cdot (2^{(X+1)(Y+1)}-4)$

We can have exactly two adjoining corner points along the $X+1$ direction in $2$ ways.  We need at least one of the other side that is not a corner and anything from the middle giving $2 \cdot (2^{X-1}-1)\cdot 2^{(X+1)(Y-1)}$  Similarly we can have two along the $Y+1$ direction $2$ ways giving $2 \cdot (2^{Y-1}-1)\cdot 2^{(X-1)(Y+1)}$

We can have exactly one corner in $4$ ways.  We need at least one of each opposite side, so $4 \cdot (2^{X-1}-1)\cdot (2^{Y-1}-1)\cdot 2^{(X-1)(Y-1)}  $

We can have no corners and need at least one interior point on each side, which gives $ (2^{X-1}-1)^2\cdot (2^{Y-1}-1)^2\cdot 2^{(X-1)(Y-1)}$

Putting it all together, we have $g(X,Y)=7\cdot (2^{(X+1)(Y+1)}-4)+2 \cdot (2^{X-1}-1)\cdot 2^{(X+1)(Y-1)}+2 \cdot (2^{Y-1}-1)\cdot 2^{(X-1)(Y+1)}+4 \cdot (2^{X-1}-1)\cdot (2^{Y-1}-1)\cdot 2^{(X-1)(Y-1)}+(2^{X-1}-1)^2\cdot (2^{Y-1}-1)^2\cdot 2^{(X-1)(Y-1)}$

The final answer if $h(X)=f(X)-2\sum_{i=1}^{X-1} g(X,i)\cdot (X-i-1)$ because a pattern of width $i$ can be translated into $X-i$ positions and we want only one of those.  The factor two comes from the fact that the wide direction can be horizontal or vertical.

Comment: just one doubt , for $X = 1$ , $h(X)$ will still be $11$ as the sum which is subtracted goes from $1$ to $X-1$ and in the case of $X = 1$ it does not get subtracted.